# How to start an android app from two activity

Tags: android

I am developing an android app in which I am signing up with my mobile number on splash screen . What I want is that signing up should be neccessary only once and first time at the time of app installation. After installing  the app, app should open from another activity , not the from splash screen. how it is possible.

Comment: You need to add SharedPrefrence "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm" to store required information. and when app open second time the you need to check value from sharedPrefrence.

Comment: This link is showing error "page not found"

Comment: Care to add some code?

Comment: Sorry for that.,, you can get details @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html]

Answer (score 4):

On successful signup of login you have to store data in `SharedPreferences`.

**AppTypeDetails is class for SharedPreferences.**

```
 AppTypeDetails.getInstance(SignUpActivity.this).setEmail(<Your Email ID>);
 AppTypeDetails.getInstance(SignUpActivity.this).setPassword(<Your Password>);
```

**AppTypeDetails.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class AppTypeDetails {

    private SharedPreferences sh;

    private AppTypeDetails() {

    }

    private AppTypeDetails(Context mContext) {
        sh = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    }

    private static AppTypeDetails instance = null;

    /**
     * 
     * @param mContext
     * @return {@link AppTypeDetails}
     */
    public synchronized static AppTypeDetails getInstance(Context mContext) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new AppTypeDetails(mContext);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    // get username
    public String getEmail() {
        return sh.getString("email", "");
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        sh.edit().putString("email", email).commit();
    }

    // get password
    public String getPassword() {
        return sh.getString("password", "");
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        sh.edit().putString("password", password).commit();
    }

    public void clear() {
        sh.edit().clear().commit();
    }

}
```

Now check below code in splash screen.

```
String email = AppTypeDetails.getInstance(SplashScreen.this).getEmail();
String pass = AppTypeDetails.getInstance(SplashScreen.this).getPassword();

if (email.trim().isEmpty() && pass.trim().isEmpty()) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Login.class);
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainScreenTabHost.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**For clear `SharedPreferences` :**

Call clear() method on logout.

Comment: @MMartin if my answer is helpful for you then accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In splash class you should check if the app runs for the first time or not. If yes so continue, if not, start the second activity. It is possible by checking a boolean, store it in shared preferences and every time check its value at startup.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SharedPrefrence.But it is not the complete answer.Show your SplashScreen check in that your user is register or not.

```
       Boolean REG_RESPONCE = new   Session_manag(getActivity()).IsSessionCheckOrCreated();
            if (REG_RESPONCE.equals(true)) {
                Intent toHomeactivity = new Intent(Splash.this, MainMenu.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(toHomeactivity);
            } else {

                Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, SignUp.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too easy to handle. What you need is a concept to how to implement this. So I am giving you the road map , do some searching on the internet about the things I am going to tell you. These steps are as under

1. I think the easy way of doing this , is to implement the shared preferences. what shared preferences do ? They will store the information of your client into the app such as his name , password
2. So when the Spalsh start first check if there are values in the shared preferences , if there are values then its mean that your user has already signed in.
3. In case of there is no value stored by the user then its mean that you need to take him to the signup activity.
4. So in this way you can take your user where you want. But there is no way to use two activities at the same time.

You can read shared preferences from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) is a nice tutorial to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can check condition on splash screen that user has already signup with number or not.for that you have to save that number in SharedPreferences.
Follow thew below steps,

Step 1 : When user open app first time splash screen will come.here you can check condition for number.At first time, when user come on app value(number) dosn't exist in SharedPreferences.so app will ask for enter number. when user enter number and submit, store that in SharedPreferences.

Step 2 : now, Second time when user come on splash screen, that condition become true because SharedPreferences has the Value(number). so you can redirect app on second activity.