# How to use SharedPreferences value to fill EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences, storage

I'd like to know how to fill EditText field with the values of SharedPreferences. My code is as follows:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(this);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key),MODE_PRIVATE);
        textViewCheck();
    }

    public void textViewCheck()
    {
        EditText sil_key = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.silent_key);
        String silent_mode_key = sil_key.getText().toString();
        EditText gen_key = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.general_key);
        String general_mode_key = gen_key.getText().toString();
        EditText vib_key = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.vibrate_key);
        String vibrate_mode_key = vib_key.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        if((sharedPreferences.contains("silent")) && (sharedPreferences.contains("general")) && (sharedPreferences.contains("vibrate")))
        {
            sil_key.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("silent","silent1"));
            gen_key.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("general","general1"));
            vib_key.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("vibrate","vibrate1"));
        }
        editor.putString("silent",silent_mode_key);
        editor.putString("general",general_mode_key);
        editor.putString("vibrate",vibrate_mode_key);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

I keep getting the same values even after changing in the EditText fields. I would like to know why I keep getting this and how to overcome this. ( I am so sorry for the previous error with getString() method, didn't notice that.Please clarify this one)

Comment: Why are you doing `String silent_mode_key = sil_key.toString();`?

Comment: You are getting `android.support.design` this because of above comment.

Comment: I am so sorry for that, could you see the updated question

Comment: Just do one thing first. Uninstall app from mobile and again install. You are getting same value may be because of sharedpreference.

Comment: Done that, but still same values. It's not displaying the default values too.

Comment: Please refer my answer for how to save data on sharedpref and get data from shared pref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676947/sharedpreferences-always-get-default-value-in-my-existing-app-but-when-created-n/34722133#34722133

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33795959/how-to-start-an-android-app-from-two-activity/33796115#33796115

Answer (score 0):

i think you may be messing when creating the strings

```
EditText sil_key = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.silent_key);
String silent_mode_key = sil_key.toString();
```

I think you meant to make it a string from the content of the edit text
like this

```
    String silent_mode_key = sil_key.getText().toString();
```

try this

```
    EditText sil_key = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.silent_key);
    String silent_mode_key = sil_key.getText().toString();
    EditText gen_key = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.general_key);
    String general_mode_key = gen_key.getText().toString();
    EditText vib_key = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.vibrate_key);
    String vibrate_mode_key = vib_key.getText().toString();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    if((sharedPreferences.contains("silent")) && (sharedPreferences.contains("general")) && (sharedPreferences.contains("vibrate")))
    {
        sil_key.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("silent","silent"));
        gen_key.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("general","general"));
        vib_key.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("vibrate","vibrate"));
    }
    editor.putString("silent",silent_mode_key);
    editor.putString("general",general_mode_key);
    editor.putString("vibrate",vibrate_mode_key);
    editor.apply();
```

Comment: I am so sorry for that, could you please see the updated question?

Answer (score 0):

try to add  `getText()` like below for all the strings:

```
EditText sil_key = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.silent_key);
    String silent_mode_key = sil_key.getText().toString();
```

Comment: I am so sorry for that, could you see the updated question

Comment: again you have updated with getString() instead of getText().

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to add this before sharedPreferences.getString

```
sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```